# How to block user login after 5 attempts ReactJS

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, authentication

I am trying to add to my login form the function that blocks users after 5 login attempts with the same username and wrong password.
I have in my MySQL table of users with boolean column isBlock that changes to true if the user tried too many times.  I want to show "user block" message if the user gets blocked.

And I'm trying to add password validation to my register page. I added some methods to check it but I'm not sure how to check the methods when I press on the REGISTER button.

(in the validation I want the password be at least 6 chars, include numbers and have at least one a-z/A-Z char.

Login Form:

```
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import axios from "axios";

class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        isBlock:false,
        showError: false,
        response: "",
        passwordLengthValid: false,
        uppercaseValid: false,
        numberValid: false
    }
    resetForm = () => {
        this.setState({
            username: '',
            password: '',
        })
    }

    // Check the length of the input
    checkPasswordLength = (password) => {
        if (password.length >= 6) {
            this.setState({
                passwordLengthValid: true
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                passwordLengthValid: false
            })
        }
    }


    // Check for an uppercase character
    checkUppercase = (password) => {
        const pattern = /[A-Z][a-z]/;
        if (pattern.test(password)) {
            this.setState({
                uppercaseValid: true
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                uppercaseValid: false
            })
        }
    }

    // Check for a number
    checkNumber = (password) => {
        const pattern = /[0-9]/;
        if (pattern.test(password)) {
            this.setState({
                numberValid: true
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                numberValid: false
            })
        }
    }

    onUsernameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        })
    }

    onPasswordChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            password: event.target.value
        })

        this.checkPasswordLength(event.target.value);
        this.checkUppercase(event.target.value);
        this.checkNumber(event.target.value);
    };
    login = () => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8989/sign-in", {
            params: {
                username: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data && response.data.length > 0 ) {
                    const cookies = new Cookies();
                    cookies.set("logged_in", response.data);
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        showError: true
                    })
                }
            })

    }

    signUp = () => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8989/create-account", {
            params: {
                username: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password,
                isBlock:this.state.isBlock
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data) {
                    this.setState({
                        response: "Your account has been created!"
                    })
                } else {
                    this.setState({showError: true, response: "This username is already taken"})
                }

            })
    }

    render() {


        const inputStyle = {
            margin: "10px",
            width: "200px"
        }

        const buttonStyle = {
            margin: "10px",
            width: "200px",
            backgroundColor: "black",
            color: "white",
            borderRadius: "5px"
        }

        const signUpButtonStyle = {
            margin: "10px",
            width: "200px",
            backgroundColor: "green",
            color: "white",
            borderRadius: "5px",
            marginTop: "20px"
        }

        const hasRequiredDetails = !(this.state.username == "" || this.state.password == "");

        return (
            <div style={{margin: "auto", width: "50%", padding: "10px"}}>
                <fieldset style={{width: "300px"}}>
                    <legend>
                        <div style={{fontSize: "20px"}}>
                            Login to your account
                        </div>
                    </legend>
                    <input style={inputStyle}
                           onChange={this.onUsernameChange}
                           value={this.state.username}
                           placeholder={"Enter username"}
                    />
                    <input type={"password"}
                            style={inputStyle}
                           onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
                           value={this.state.password}
                           placeholder={"Enter password"}
                    />
                    <div>
                        <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={this.login} disabled={!hasRequiredDetails} >Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button style={signUpButtonStyle} onClick={this.signUp} disabled={!hasRequiredDetails} >Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button className="button--secondary" onClick={this.resetForm}>
                            Reset
                        </button>
                    </div>


                </fieldset>
                <div style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.response}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a state like `mistakeCount`

```
this.state = {
     mistakeCount: 0
     …
}
```

Now when an error occurs in login:

```
this.setState({
        showError: true,
        mistakeCount: this.state.mistakeCount + 1
 })
```

At last, you need to block the account when this reaches 5. You can check either after receiving error or before sending a login request.

Comment: i thought about this solution but it will keep counting if i change the user name and get more errors. and how can i update it in my db when i reach 5 mistake?

Comment: You can reset the `mistakeCount` to 0, when you are changing the username, in `onUsernameChange` handler.

Comment: And on Error Handler, you can check if `mistakeCount` is already 5, and in that case, you can make another API endpoint to update the according field on the backend.

Comment: sound good i will try it. what about the password validaion?

Comment: Sorry, I could not reply as i went to bed. But yes, you can obviously follow @Richard Zhan  's suggestions